# Copy multiple different lines in text file

Tags: copy, lines

I have 10 lines in notepad n i want to copy only 2nd and 7th line. The way we copy folders and files using ctrl and shift. Can anyone please let me know any shortcut for the same.

Comment: Depends on editor if they are providing the functionality you want ..

Comment: Any idea which editor provides this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [Atom text editor](https://atom.io/) for the functionality you needed :

Follow the steps :
1 Open the file .
2 Move the curse above the line number until symbol changes `I` to arrow symbol .
3 Now press `CTRL` key and select the line you want .